# Feynman rules in Grassmann variables

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, grassmann-numbers

I'm given the following integral $$ Z[w] = \frac{1}{ (2 \pi)^{n/2}} \int d^n x \prod_{i=1}^n d \overline{\theta}_i d \theta_i \exp \left( - \overline{\theta}_i \partial_j w_i (x) \theta_j - \frac{1}{2} w_i(x) w_i(x) \right). \tag{1}$$ Here $w_i(x)$ are functions of the $n$ real variables. I calculated that $$ Z[w] = 1.\tag{2} $$

Now, for the particular example we take $$w_i(x) = x_i + \frac{1}{2} g_{ijk} x_j x_k\tag{3}$$ with $g_{ijk} = g_{ikj} = g_{kij}$  (assuming $g_{ijk}$ are small), I now need to find the Feynman rules for the perturbative expansion of $Z[w]$.

I'm not really sure how to start, can someone help me out please?
How does an interaction vertex in a Feynman diagram looks like then?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/398781/2451